# why Visual studio code can not find pandas when it is already installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I followed this instruction https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial to install pandas. and when I check it is installed:

```
python -m pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\mansour\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\mansour\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2020.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in c:\users\mansour\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.19.1)        
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\mansour\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\mansour\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)
```

I am running this command in Visual Studio Code Python terminal.

but in my code, I have this error:

[image]

and when I run the application, I am getting this error:

[image]

Why I am getting this error?

Comment: make sure you point VSC to the correct interpreter. Also, in my experience, `pylint` is pretty slow and a little buggy on VSC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may be the reason for the environment. please check the correct environment is select or not while running the code.
I Think you have installed in different environments and running the code in different environments.